# What does ものと見て, mean?

Tags: grammar, syntax

> 先日の佐伯真一さん殺人事件と、昨夜の四ッ星重工爆発炎上事故…それに、誘拐および殺人未遂事件を調べている警視庁は、この事件の裏で、大掛かりな軍事汚職事件が絡んでいる**ものと見て、**真相の究明に全力を尽くすと発表しています。

The Superior Police Headquarters is investigating the murder ... of Mr. Shinichi Saeki, and the fire last night of the Yotsuboshi corporation. Also a kidnapping and attempted murder. It is believed that after all ... this hides a matter of weapons and corruption. The Police announced ... to dedicate all their efforts so that the truth comes to light.

An English dubbed movie version (text I extracted):

> The police have found a connection between the murder incident...
>   ...the explosion at the Yotsuboshi Lab, and a kidnapping case.
>   This conspiracy involves political officials who were behind these incidents.
>   The police are still investigating for further details of the relationship...

Answer (score 6):

> 「先日の佐伯真一さん殺人事件と、昨夜の四ッ星重工爆発炎上事故…それに、誘拐および殺人未遂事件を調べている**警視庁は**、この事件の裏で、大掛かりな軍事汚職事件が絡んでいる**ものと見て**、真相の究明に全力を尽くすと発表しています。」

「見る」, in this context, means none other than "**to judge**".  It is often used for that meaning in news reporting regarding police investigations.

The subject of 「見て」 is 「警視庁{けいしちょう}」 = "the (Tokyo) Metropolitan Police Department".

> 「～～と見る」 = "to judge that ~~"

Do remember that we also often use the passive voice forms 「～～と見られる/見られている」 for this meaning.

In the two translations you have provided, the first one uses "**It is believed that**" for 「～～と見て」, which is alright.

The second one is so "free" that 「～～と見て」 is **not** translated anywhere.  That kind of translation would be of little to no help unless you are already quite fluent.

My own translation of:

> 「警視庁は、この事件の裏で、大掛かりな軍事汚職事件が絡んでいるものと見て、真相の究明に全力を尽くすと発表しています。」

would be:

> "The Metropolitan Police Department has made the judgement that a large-scale military corruption case is involved behind this incident and it has announced that it would put forth every effort in determining the truth."

Comment: You work miracles! Thanks for the reply. I was getting pretty desperate with this one. I was just gonna have to rely on google translate and hope for the best before you came along. Nobody in reddit wanted to touch this question even with a 10 foot pole, since I'm always known for asking the toughest questions around. With my questions, I separate the real translators from the rookies.