# What does と見て mean in this context?

Tags: translation, particle-と

I was trying to translate some phrases from an anime and と見て appeared, which I have no idea what it is. It all happened while the protagonist was watching the news.

> 本日未明桜見町の路地裏で

> 刃物で刺された女性の遺体が見つかりました

> 桜見警察では犯行の手口から

> 桜見町を中心とした一連の通り魔による犯行と見て

> 調査本部を設け調査に乗り出す方針です

Comment: What's your best take on what is being said?

Comment: Earlier today, in a sakuramichou alley, the (identified) corpse of a girl was found who had been pierced by a sharp object. with the Sakura police, based on the crime technique Believing that the crime was caused by the same killer who played a central role in Sakura Michou, so the policy establishes an investigation headquarters, for preparatory investigation

Comment: Closely related: [What does ものと見て, mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69713/5010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "と見て" in Japanese is used to indicate a judgment or assessment of a situation. It's similar to the English expressions "to view as" or "to regard as." In the context of your translation, it seems to be used in a news report or a similar formal context.

Let's break down the specific sentence:

桜見警察では犯行の手口から
桜見町を中心とした一連の通り魔による犯行と見て
調査本部を設け調査に乗り出す方針です
Translated, this would be:

"Based on the method of the crime, the Sakurami Police Department"
"considers it to be an act committed by the same serial perpetrator who has been targeting Sakurami Town,"
"and plans to set up an investigative headquarters to start a thorough investigation."
So, "と見て" in this context is used to express the police department's assessment or view that the crime is linked to a series of similar incidents in the area. It's a formal way of stating an opinion or judgment, often used in official statements or reports.